# Create FTP account with vsftpd limited to one folder only?

Tags: server, ssh, ftp, vsftpd

Have a fresh Ubuntu install 14.04 on digital ocean. Just installed vsftpd using this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html#vsftpd-userauth-configuration

The only things I have done thus far are uncomment `write_enable=YES` and `chroot_local_user=YES`, I did nothing else.

This is my first time working with this software.

I need to know how to create separate FTP accounts limited to viewing/uploading/downloading to a specific folder in the `public_html` directory.

It was easy to do this on cPanel on shared hosting, so i'm hoping it's possible.

I am SSH'ing through terminal into the server.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, you have to create users just like the way you create system users, but you may have to use custom options such as shell, home dir ... etc while adding the user. Refer `man useradd` for custom attributes and also refer [**vsftpd - Ubuntu documentation**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd).